# Do action if button clicked for 3 times

Tags: asp.net

I want to do some action if button clicked for 3 times. Just like if users enters a wrong password for 3 times the page the page must be redirected to another page or something.

How to do action in ASP.NET C# if button clicked for 3rd time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a session variable.

Another solution could be having a column in the users table named LoginAttempt(int)(default 0), how I would use that column is

Let's say you have a table in your databese called TblUsers with these columns

1. Id,
2. UserName,
3. Password,
4. LoginAttempt.

And let's say you have two TextBoxes on your Login.aspx page

1. `TextBoxUserName`,
2. `TextBoxPassword`.

Let's say you have one record in your TblUsers like this

```
Id           : 1
UserName     : rammstein
Password     : ohnedich
LoginAttempt : 0
```

Now, you are in your Login.aspx.cs code

you have a method and in it you have

```
TblUsers user = new TblUsers();
```

And you have a `bool login = false;`.
You've got the username from `TextBoxUserName.Text`, you check if a user with this username exists then if it exist you do the below code.

Let's follow this scenerio

The given user tried to login with

```
UserName:rammstein 
Password:duhast
```

Checked your database with username rammstein and found it, and took that record in your `TblpUsers user` then you checked whether `user.Password` and `TextBoxPassword.Text` matches.Well it won't match for the above example because

`user.Password` is `ohnedich` however `TextBox.Password` is `duhast`.This means the login is not successfull so you set false to your `bool login`.

Everything else belongs to the below code with `if-else` condition

```
if(user.LoginAttempt < 3){

      if(!login)
      {
          user.LoginAttempt = user.LoginAttempt + 1;
      }
      else
      {
          user.LoginAttempt = 0;
      }
}
else
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: What is `user` and `login` here?

Comment: @KarsM I added some explanation, let me know if you need more help.Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a user has taken an action fox "x" times you need to store it somehwere. If you're using a relation database you could for example call a table LoginAttempts and there you store all unsuccesfull logins. When you have that table you can build your logic against it.

Comment: That's true... and he could probably just use the default provider.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple solutions:

1) Session variable (Okay solution)

2) Static class variable (Not a good solution)

3) DB record field (Best solution)

4) Pass flag variable back and forth between view and controller (not a very good idea).

5) Browser cookie (can be cleared)

Comment: Do NOT use a static variable to store the number of login attempts - that one value will be shared by all users!

Comment: Do NOT use cookie, what is stopping the user from deleting that cookie between the attempts!

Comment: @Hans - lol...maybe I should include a disclaimer on unsafe and safe practices.

Comment: @Hans - you can use static classes if you use key/value pairs with the key being an identifier, but then you are wasting resources mimicking session. I agree that DB is the best approach for this.

Comment: @TomasJansson - I agree. Most users won't do that, but that is why I had `can be cleared` in parenthesis.